# Wx.FileDialog.ShowModal not working in python 3.7 in windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, wxpython

I am develoing an app where I am using wxpython to save the files.

Following code snippet works fine in python 2.7 but not in python 3.7

```
import wx
obj = wx.FileDialog( None, "Export Report", "", "", "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.Fd_OVERWRITE_PROMPT )
obj.ShowModal()
```

This code opens a pop-up window to save a file in python 2.7 but in 3.7, ShowModal method returns None instead of a interger and doesn't open any pop up

Comment: FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT? (works in Linux)

Comment: Then which flag should be used for windows?

Comment: I only draw to your attention the fact that, in your code, you have Fd_OVERWRITE_PROMPT